# How can i use case within the pivot in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have the query output as below using pivot, i want to change null value to zero.How to do it?
Query :

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME([TypeDescription]) 
                    from tbReadingType
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'') 


set @query = 'SELECT *
FROM (
    select   Rt.TypeDescription,Rc.Amount as Amount,Rc.FinancialYearID,Rc.ParentID
  from tbRunningCost Rc join tbReadingType Rt on
  Rc.ReadingTypeID=Rt.ReadingTypeID group by  Rt.TypeDescription,Rc.FinancialYearID,Rc.Quantity,Rc.ReadingTypeID ,Rc.ParentID ,Amount
  ) AS src 
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Amount)
    FOR TypeDescription IN ('+@cols+' )
)AS pvt' 

execute(@query)
```

Output :

```
FinancialYearID    |ParentID   |Aerobic Count    |Building Cleaning    |Cold Water (Temperature)    |Electricity Meter   | Gas Meter    |Gas Oil    |Grounds Maintenance
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
22                 |245        |NULL             |NULL                 |NULL                        |NULL                | NULL         |NULL       |NULL
20                 |247        |NULL             |NULL                 |NULL                        |NULL                | 548          |NULL       |NULL
20                 |250        |NULL             |NULL                 |NULL                        |1                   | NULL         |NULL       |NULL
21                 |250        |NULL             |NULL                 |NULL                        |NULL                | NULL         |NULL       |NULL
22                 |250        |NULL             |NULL                 |NULL                        |NULL                | NULL         |NULL       |NULL
20                 |254        |NULL             |NULL                 |NULL                        |15455               | NULL         |NULL       |NULL
20                 |256        |NULL             |NULL                 |NULL                        |403                 | 560          |NULL       |NULL
21                 |256        |NULL             |NULL                 |NULL                        |NULL                | NULL         |NULL       |NULL
22                 |256        |NULL             |581.087              |NULL                        |NULL                | NULL         |NULL       |581.087
20                 |257        |NULL             |NULL                 |NULL                        |92792               | 1413         |NULL       |NULL
21                 |257        |NULL             |NULL                 |NULL                        |NULL                | NULL         |NULL       |NULL
22                 |257        |NULL             |NULL                 |NULL                        |NULL                | NULL         |NULL       |NULL
21                 |262        |NULL             |NULL                 |NULL                        |NULL                | NULL         |NULL       |NULL
22                 |262        |NULL             |NULL                 |NULL                        |NULL                | NULL         |NULL       |NULL
22                 |263        |NULL             |377.245              |NULL                        |NULL                | NULL         |NULL       |NULL
20                 |264        |NULL             |NULL                 |NULL                        |NULL                | NULL         |NULL       |NULL
20                 |265        |NULL             |NULL                 |NULL                        |34427               | NULL         |NULL       |NULL
22                 |266        |NULL             |360                  |NULL                        |NULL                | NULL         |NULL       |NULL
20                 |267        |NULL             |NULL                 |NULL                        |NULL                | NULL         |NULL       |NULL
21                 |267        |NULL             |NULL                 |NULL                        |NULL                | NULL         |NULL       |NULL
22                 |267        |NULL             |NULL                 |NULL                        |NULL                | NULL         |NULL       |NULL
```

Comment: Personally I suggest against the `PIVOT` operator and use a Cross Tab instead. They are easier to work with and more functionality (such as pivoting on 2 columns). For what you need, it'kl be far easier to then put an `ISNULL` in your logic with a Cross Tab; otherwise you'll need to build a value for `@cols` full of `ISNULL` too.

Comment: Try to change  SUM(Amount) to ISNULL(SUM(Amount),0.0) in the PIVOT operator

Comment: Also, why are you grouping in your sub query, when you have no aggregates..?

Answer (score 0):

This is very much a blind guess, in the absence of sample data and expected results, but I *think* this'll work for what you're after. If not, it'll very likely get you on the right path, and your best friend will help you get to the end:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = N'SELECT Rc.Financial,' + NCHAR(10) + NCHAR(13) + 
           N'       Rc.ParentID,' + NCHAR(10) + NCHAR(13) +
           STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT
                         N',' + NCHAR(10) + NCHAR(13) +
                         N'       SUM(CASE Rt.TypeDescription WHEN ' + QUOTENAME(Rt.TypeDescription,'''') + N' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(Rt.[TypeDescription])
                  FROM tbReadingType
                  FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,3,N'') +  
           N'FROM tbRunningCost Rc' + NCHAR(10) + NCHAR(13) + 
           N'     JOIN tbReadingType Rt ON Rc.ReadingTypeID=Rt.ReadingTypeID' + NCHAR(10) + NCHAR(13) + 
           N'GROUP BY Rc.FinancialYearID,' + NCHAR(10) + NCHAR(13) + 
           N'         Rc.ParentID;';

PRINT @SQL; --your best friend

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Good luck!